# Protractor testing for Google API address field

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor, automated-tests, ui-automation

Please help with the Protractor testing within Google API field. The scenario is, I was able to sendkeys my value or location I want to find,but unable to select the first occurrence because I cannot select or keydown my cursor.And is there a way to get the innerHTML in Protractor? Kindly help. Thank you

script:
element(by.id('address_permanentAddress_personal_details')).sendKeys('LocationAddress');
        browser.actions().click(element(by.css('.pac-container.pac-logo.hdpi .pac-item:first-child'))).perform()

browser.sleep(1000);
        element(by.id('address_permanentAddress_personal_details')).sendKeys(protractor.Key.TAB);

[Google API Javascript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJaDE.jpg)

NOV 25 screenshot

[timeout error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOBil.jpg)
[myscript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrvPz.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I select an item from google's location input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58235008/how-do-i-select-an-item-from-googles-location-input-field)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `actions` class to select the location dropdown value. Try the below option

```
element(by.id('address_permanentAddress_personal_details')).sendKeys('LocationAddress'); 
var dropEle = element(by.css('.pac-container.pac-logo.hdpi .pac-item:first-child'));
await browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(dropEle),5000,'Wait for first drop value');
await dropEle.click();
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: .Thank you for the guide and assistance. I really appreciate it. I did what you suggested and I encountered the timeout message. Please see screenshot above. Kindly let me know. Thank you and good day.

Comment: @user3766083 Could you try with increasing the timeout based on the time it takes to load the location suggestion in drop d\own.

Comment: I tried increasing the wait from 5000 to 8000 but still no avail. it is failing. is there a script or command or setup i need to put in config or spec? Thank you.          
 await browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(dropEle),8000,'Wait for first drop value');
    await dropEle.click();

Comment: can check with `elementToBeVisible` instead of `elementToBeClickable`?

Comment: I tried using the elementToBeVisible but it says it is not a function. - here is my error. Failed: ExpectedConditions.elementToBeVisible is not a function