# Protractor can't perform click on <li> tag

Tags: javascript, angular, protractor, e2e-testing, angular-e2e

I'm tring to make an e2e test of my application but I can't perform click on search engine.
This is the example I want to try to "click" on the first element but protractor stuck on the image below :

[image]

The website that I'm taliking about is this : https://rent.decathlon.it/

The result is a timeout error, so the element is not clicked.

This is the protractor code :

```
import { AppPage } from './app.po';
import {browser, by, element, logging} from 'protractor';
import {SearchBoxWizard} from '../elements/searchbox_wizard';

describe('workspace-project App', () => {
  let page: AppPage;

  beforeEach(() => {
    page = new AppPage();
  });

  it('shoud open select item', async () => {
    await page.navigateTo();
    browser.sleep(500);
    const searchBoxWizardElements = new SearchBoxWizard();
    await searchBoxWizardElements.getLocationInput().click();
    await searchBoxWizardElements.getLocationInput().clear();
    await searchBoxWizardElements.getLocationInput().sendKeys('Milano');
    await browser.sleep(500);
    element(by.css(`.autocomplete-search > ul > li:nth-child(1) > span`)).click();
  });

  afterEach(async () => {
    // Assert that there are no errors emitted from the browser
    const logs = await browser.manage().logs().get(logging.Type.BROWSER);
    expect(logs).not.toContain(jasmine.objectContaining({
      level: logging.Level.SEVERE,
    } as logging.Entry));
  });
});
```

Someone have an idea of why?

I'm using this stack :

- Angular 8
- protractor 5.6 or 7
- Karma 4.1
- Jasmin 3

Regards

**EDIT** :

I notice very strange behavior, If I check if body is displayed, protractor can't see it, this is the code...

```
  it('shoud open select item', async () => {
    await page.navigateTo();
    const searchBoxWizardElements = new SearchBoxWizard();
    const cookiePolicy = new CookiePolicy();
    await cookiePolicy.getAcceptCta().click();
    await searchBoxWizardElements.getLocationInput().click();
    await searchBoxWizardElements.getLocationInput().clear();
    await searchBoxWizardElements.getLocationInput().sendKeys('Milano').then(
      async _ => {
        await browser.sleep(2500);
        await element(by.css('body')).isDisplayed();
      });
  });
```

I think it is something like "loosing" app focus... I don't know...

Have you got any idea?

Regards

Comment: is this google API location input? if yes, here is the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58238668/9150146 please upvote if works

Comment: No, I test that solution but it doesn't work... I don't understand why...

Comment: there may be many errors. What error do you get? at which step? do you have iframes in html code of the page? is it a googple API dropdown?

Comment: Yes, sorry... The error is "timeout", so the element is not visible... I try, as you can see, also with the `body` tag, but when I call the sendKey function is stop to be visible.. I don't use the google API dropdown but I make the call in the controller, I receive the results and then I create a ul/li dropdown... It is so strange, I can't understand why....

Answer (score -1):

1. it is definitely a google api. I checked that. Requests are coming back from `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/js`
2. You missed `await` in many places. You need to read about promises and way to handle is with `await`

`browser.sleep` needs `await`

`.click()` needs `await`

Comment: .. do you read all question and the edit? All promises are resolved, I say that I'm using the GoogleAPI but pupulating my array and usign my foor loop... Did you test my code? Can you provide a snippet of solution?

Comment: 1. the answer was provided before the edit. 2. your code can't be tested on my end because I have no idea what your `page`, `SearchBoxWizard` or `CookiePolicy` are. 3. This is a wrong way for checking if body is displayed. 4. good luck