# Is there a possible way to locate auto-suggested dropdown of input field with Protractor?

Tags: javascript, protractor, ui-automation

I am trying to automate the following case with JS and Protractor: I open https://www.booking.com, then input 'Paris' destination searchbox and select the first option in auto-suggested dropdown. However I can't find this element in Elements inspector console.

The element is following:

[image]

Does anyone have idea how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

that's very complex case to solve when you're a beginner. I recommend to skip it for now. But if you insist see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/58238668/9150146

But in theory - booking is company A, they rely on maps developed by google (company B). The way it works is A has an application that gets an information from B and appends it to the page. So elements from B can be found in the bottom of the page. But the challenge is locators change

Comment: if helped, please accept and upvote both answers